# Round down very large or small float by scale

Tags: php, regex, math, rounding-error

I have next situation, I have some qty it can be very big or very small float like:

3698541.2569854 or 0.569875255456.

Also, I have some scale
or min step, like

0.0001 or 1000.00.

My challenge is round my qty to nearest down number by step. Example:

```
$qty = 323.659;
$step = 0.1;
// result must be 323.6
```

I have my own solution, it work well, but i have problem with wery large nums.

```
private function roundDownByStep($qty, $stepSize) {
    $stepSize = sprintf('%.16f', $stepSize);
    $stepSize = preg_replace('/|\\..+?\\K0+$/', "", $stepSize);
    $precision = strlen(substr(strrchr($stepSize, "."), 1));
    if ($precision == 1 && $stepSize >= 1) {
        $precision = 0;
    }
    if ($precision == 0) {
        $subArg = 1/$stepSize;
        return floor(($qty * $subArg)) / $subArg;
    } else {
        $subArg = bcdiv('1', $stepSize, $precision);
        $result = floor(bcmul($qty,  $subArg, $precision));
        $result = sprintf('%.16f', $result);
        $result = preg_replace('/|\\..+?\\K0+$/', "", $result);
        return bcdiv($result, $subArg, $precision);
    }
}
```

You can try it on
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/333f58c1487e86e53dde64c26930b57e1f9e0fe8

Comment: The [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function has `$precision` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating a simple task:

```
function cutAtPrecision($number, $precision) {
    return intval($number * (1 / $precision)) / (1 / $precision);
}

echo cutAtPrecision(323.659, 0.01); // 323.65
```